# OpenCV, python - namedWindow; WINDOW_KEEPRATIO; Linux vs Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, opencv

I'm working on a cross-platform system, and have noted that using opencv for showing of images is a bit different on Windows and Ubuntu/Linux.  I'm running these from the Anaconda distribution of Python 3.5, using Spyder as the IDE.

OpenCV is version 3.1.0 on the Windows side.
OpenCV is version 3.2.0 on the Linux side.

Snippet of code is here:

```
window_name = 'image_A'
cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
cv2.imshow(window_name, named_image_a)
cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, 480, 320)

window_name = 'image_B'
cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL | cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
cv2.imshow(window_name, named_image_b)
cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, 480, 320)
```

On both the Linux and Windows side, both windows open to the same size and location - great.

However, regardless of the settings for the namedWindow on the Windows side, the images always are allowed to scale in FREERATIO mode, which isn't what I want or need.

On the Linux side, the images always open in KEEPRATIO mode!

Running both of these from an iPython console, with the graphics set the Qt5 backend.  According to:

https://fossies.org/dox/opencv-3.2.0/tutorial_display_image.html

...those tags only mean something when using the Qt5 option.

What is wrong or off here?

There's a tangential question why the same versions of OpenCV can't be installed on both; used

conda install -c menpo opencv3

for both, but this issue seems pretty basic, so version differences may not be the culprit.

Looks like you can't install 3.2.0 from menpo, though:

conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0
Fetching package metadata ...............

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - opencv3 3.2.0*

Comment: Yeah the most recent version from `menpo` is 3.1.0. You can grab it straight from the OpenCV GitHub though. `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv` and `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib` for the additional packages. Are you looking to scale the *images* upon resizing or the *window* for the image, or both? Is it the image, or the window that is scaling without the ratio? AFAIK `KEEPRATIO` doesn't keep the ratio of the window steady---only the image.

Comment: Looking to keep the images the correct aspect ratio.  On the Linux side, if you take an image that is 100 px wide by 50 px high, for example, you can make the window as big or as small as you like, but the image always has an aspect ratio of 2.0.   So KEEPRATIO does what we need.  I'm wondering if OpenCV 3.1 is the problem here, or if it is something else.  There's also http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv .